# MVC3: Get EditorFor html code without the HTML Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to access the EditorFor HTML code so I can add an object created by an Ajax call to the collection of objects for an object I have.

I have everything else in place for the replacement of the certain elements of the string for the html code, I just need a way to get the html code of the editorfor for the object without creating an html helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the ajax form to accept a JSON object that accepted the manual HTML copied from the editorfor for the specific model I was working with.